# Click in pdf file goes to indicated place

Tags: pdftex

When we do compiling tex file, we have a pdf file. In some pdf file (In online there exists a lot of such files), if we click, for instance, tex formula in the context, then we moved into tex formula paragraph or page.

Or in content page, if we click a section, then **we move into the section** page

How do we write in tex file to do this ? I think that we need the some package But I can not programming. If you have package, then can you give me ?

I usually use the following :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}\usepackage[hmargin=0.5in, vmargin=0.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multimedia, hfont, hangul}
\newtheorem{fac}{Fact} \newtheorem{idea}{IDEA}\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{con}{Conjecture}\newtheorem{exa}{Example}\newtheorem{exe}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{form}{Formula} \newtheorem{prf}{Proof}
\newtheorem{rmk}{Remark}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

In here we have a such fuctioning ? If so, please tell me about it.

Thank in advace.

Comment: Normally you don't have to do whatever: this is managed with a synchronisation file (`.synctex` or `.synctex.gz`). What's required it to configure your editor for that, and use a viewer which doesn't lock  .pdf files and understands these synchronisation files. What is your system?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. system ? What kind of system ?

Comment: I mean MiKTeX or TeX Live? which editor do you use? Which pdfviewer?

Comment: MikTeX-KTUG 2003 (Here KTUG may means Korean user) And my viewer is Acrobat Reader DC ( In online, when I download someone's pdf file, such functioning works in my viewer )

Comment: 2003?!!! It is totally outdated. You should upgrade to the latest version. At the time .synctex files didn't exist. Don't use Acrobat Reader, as it it locks .pdf files. The best choice, in my opinion, is SumatraPDF: very small (4Mo to download, 11Mo installed, vs >250 Mo for Acrobat Reader), ultra-fast, exists in 64 bits, understands .synctex files.

Comment: @Bernard I'm not sure the OP is asking about synchronisation with the source because they say that it works when they download somebody's file, which suggests whatever it is, it works when they download a PDF without the source. I think they're asking about hyperlinks and need to load `hyperref`. But obviously an updated TeX system is surely needed, all the same.

Comment: @cfr: I guess you're right. I had misunderstood what he/she asks. Anyway it's not contradicting what I wrote, and it's not bad to change Adobe's monster for another pdf viewer.

Comment: The PDF driver for TeX supports some extra features which are used by hyperref.  If you open a PDF file with some editors (your latex editor should work), you will be able to see the PDF commands in the raw.

Comment: Are you just asking about adding hyperlinks from one part of the document to another? If so then you should upgrade your TeX system and then add the command `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your preamble. Now `\label`, `\ref` and `\cite`, for example, all generate hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thank you for your consistent helps :
  Bolker, Bernard, cfr, Kormylo, Andrew Thank you for your comments.

My old miktex is version 2.3 so that I may not be given from updating place, since it does not provide service. So fortunately I equip version 2.9 from web It works well with acrobat reader DC The following is my example.

> \documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
>
> \usepackage{color, hyperref}     %%<-
>
> \usepackage{graphicx}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> Critical Point Theory 90 \eqref{exa1}   %%<-
>   Well known theory \eqref{thm1}  %%<-
>
> \begin{exa}\label{exa1}    %%<-
>
> In ...
>
> \end{exa}
>
> \begin{thm}\label{thm1}   %%<-
>
> If ...
>
> \end{thm}