# About error " could not start default compiler : PdfLaTex "

Tags: miktex, texstudio, windows

Recently I install texstudio. (My mitex is version 2.9)

But when I compile the the following popup appears

> could not start default compiler : PdfLaTex : pdflatex.exe - synctex =1 - interaction=nonstopmode

What is a problem ? Thank in advance

((1) When I use winedt and miktex version 2.2, we must do "general" and "root" in miktex options in winedt But similar action is needed in texstudio in my thought Right ?

(2) **my system** : Long ago I install miktex 2.3 and winedt. So in winedt option => roots I added localtexmf, texmf and so on.

Recently I install miktex 2.9 and texstudio In winedt, if I click option, then I can see the refreshed letter "miktex" in option popup. So this winedt use version 2.9 ? But roots still use folders in version 2.3

The reason why I install 2.9 is to use hyperref so that I now can use hyperref. )

[Add]--------------------------

I installed miktex 2.9 to use hyperref but there was some problem in the above 
In the following question I realized that in miktex 2.3 we can use hyperref So I can use hyperref in DVI and Pdf files

[Click in pdf file goes to indicated place](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304785/click-in-pdf-file-goes-to-indicated-place)

Comment: Is the problem specific to TeXStudio? Can you compile on the command line?

Comment: I do not know : this is a specific to Texstudio And I cannot understand second question.

Comment: What happens if you open a command line/terminal and run the command `pdflatex`?

Comment: When I compile, then message is the following : Error: Could not start the command: "C:/Users/user/MiKTeX 2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.cfg" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "document".tex

Comment: open a command line ? How can I do this ?

Comment: Press the start button (or press 'Windows key'+R) and type "cmd" then press enter. [The black window that shows up is the command line.](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/7-ways-launch-command-prompt-windows-7-windows-8) Now type "tex --version" and press enter. What shows up?

Comment: I will add more about my system in OP

Comment: @HKLee: Then obviously a part of miktex 2.3 is still on your system, you have to remove that before installing 2.9...

Comment: @HKLee: Or rather change the paths, so that it now directs to miktex 2.9, instead of 2.3

Comment: How can we change ?

Comment: Frankly winedt -> version 2.3 (Now I use) and texstudio -> version 2.9 Possible ?